# Sublime Text 2 instant file search replace key binding

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, sublime-text-2

Instant file search (`File: Search Files`) is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> by default in my installation of Sublime Text 2. I can't find that combination in `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap`.

On my keyboard layout that conflicts with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> combination which should be producing a left bracket <kbd>[</kbd>.

How can I prevent Sublime Text 2 to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for instant file search so that a left bracket is produced as it should be in my locale?

Comment: Removed answer because of updated question.  Since windows interprets AltGr as Ctrl + Alt.  With sublime only, your answer seems like the only way.  If you wanted a system wide change to AltGr, you could remap the key with sharpkeys or something similar. Or maybe autohotkey and make it run only when sublime is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows understands <kbd>AltGr</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, and therefore <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will be understood as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

A quick workaround is to override the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to insert the desired character by inputting that shortcut in user key-bindings. Use the menu to get to the key-bindings:

```
Preferences > Key Bindings - User
```

Or directly edit the `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` file, and add the appropriate binding to insert your desired character. For example:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+f"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "["} }
]
```